# How to embed a song in a pdf?

Tags: embedding, songs

How can I create a document that has a song playing in the back with `(La)TeX`? Is it even possible?

My hunch is that if you can embed video, there should be a way to embed music... but what is the best way to do it?  I guess having a black box playing a song is possible, but something tells me there should be a `beTeX` way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) package has support for embedding audio only, as well as video.

An example from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  flashvars={
    source=http://www.openbsd.org/songs/song49.mp3
    &autoPlay=true
  },
  transparent
]{\color{blue}\fbox{Listen to OpenBSD 4.9 release song}}{APlayer.swf}
\end{document}
```

The UI for this is a simple button to download the song and play it.

**Note:** The PDF output will only work in Adobe Reader 9, but no version greater than 9.4.1 on Linux, as per the `media9` documentation.

Comment: Nice. Do you know if `evince` supports it? Mine doesn't.